# Upload Image from Unity via PHP and stored it in a folder

Tags: php, sql, unity-game-engine

Does anyone know how to upload Images from Unity to SQL database via PHP script?

I am using xampp to simulate my SQL

Currently I am  able to open a *fileDialog* from unity application.

The user already able to select a picture and I am able to get the **filePath** of the image(e.g.: C:/Users/admin/Pictures/testImage.jpg)

However, I am a little bit stuck on how to use the **filepath** to upload and store the image in a database folder in SQL via PHP.

Could someone please show me how to do it?

Comment: There are a lot of examples of sending data to webforms.  Id suggest finding some of those.  the filepath is only relevant in unity, you send the picture to the PHP script and then it can put it where it likes.. and do whatever you like with it

Comment: @rene: hi Rene thank you for your information. Do you perhaps have an example code i can follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the file as byte array and then send the binary data to anywhere you want. Should be compatible with most unity platforms, but I'm not sure for WebGL.

I don't think it's a good idea to store files in a database thought. You can have your server save the image somewhere and just store the path to the saved image in your database.

```
using System.IO;


Start(){
    //You can load the image as a byte array
    byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\SampleImage.png");

    //You can then load it to a texture
    Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(2, 2);
    tex.LoadImage(imageAsset.bytes);

    //Or you can send the binary data to any web server
    StartCoroutine(SendFile(byteArray));
}


IEnumerator SendFile(byte[] bytes){
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddBinaryData("myImage", bytes, "myImage.png", "image/png");

    using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://www.my-server.com/myform", form))
    {
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yeepp..., it works on the editor and PC. At least I am one step forward because of you. Thank youu very muchh..!! ^_^
Now I need to find a way to do it in WebGL platform.

Comment: It wouldn't be impossible, but it's complicated. You would have to make a JS plugin and interact with it. Found this - maybe it will help you https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-do-i-let-the-user-load-an-image-from-their-harddrive-into-a-webgl-app.380985/#post-2474594